# Xamarin - Function inside Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread not calling correctly

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms, invoke

I am creating a QR code in Xamarin, and I am calling the generation of the QR code inside `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` so that I can update the QR code dynamically, every time new input is added.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                QRCodeView.IsVisible = true;
                QRCodeView = null;
                QRCodeView = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
                {
                    BarcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                    BarcodeOptions = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
                    {
                        Height = 150,
                        Width = 150,
                        PureBarcode = true
                    },
                    BarcodeValue = await SetQrContent(),

                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
                };
            });
```

In my function `SetQrContent()` the QR code is passed the new values. **However** I think this function is being called too late, as the new QR code's values are not being set correctly, causing my QR code to not change when input is changing.

Am I using `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to run SetQrContent before you starting to invoke on the MainThred?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the issue remains

Comment: The IsVisible property assignment is not sensible, it belongs *after* the new statement.  Also a good place to put a breakpoint to ensure the code actually executes.  Async code has a knack for hiding exceptions, if you don't check for them then they'll fall in the bit-bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try only setting the `BarcodeValue` when changing the QrContent.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    // Don't reset the view, only reset the value on the barcode
    QRCodeView.BarcodeValue = await SetQrContent();
});
```

When a control is already added to a page, only change the properties of the view rather than creating a new view. When you created a new `ZXingBarcodeImageView`, the new view wasn't added to the page resulting in still seeing old data.